# Separating Entity Framework 6 projects into layers

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I am going through a tutorial on Entity Framework 6 and trying to implement this into a test project. This would be targeting ASP .Net webforms but i think the principle would be the same for MVC projects.

I have 3 projects DAL, BAL and Webforms project.

I create a Class Library called DAL, Install EF 6. Add ADO.Net Entity Data Model, link to the database. This has 2 tables for ease Customer and Addresses. The connection string is stored in the app.config file.

```
Table 1 (Customers)- Id, Firstname, Surname
Table 2 (Addresses)- Id, PrimaryAddress, CustomerId
```

1. I see a .tt file and expanding it i see all the classes resembling my database tables. If i want to add another method i.e.

   ```
   Public string GetCustomerFullName
   {
     return Firstname + " " + Surname;
   }
   ```

Where and how would i do this on the DAL project? I was thinking of the Class created when expanding the .tt file (i.e. Customer class) but i have a sneaky feeling this may get overridden if i was to regenerate /refresh some part of the ADO.Net Entity Data Model file, e.g. if a table is added or something?

2. I create another Class Library called BAL (this is where i would like to call all of the CRUD operations). Install EF6 from Nuget. I add reference to the DAL project. Currently the tutorial adds a new Dbcontext instance for every method i.e. Add, Update etc within the same project.

How do i reference the DbContext created in DAL project in this project? I've read a mixture of threads that a new context could give odd behaviour where others feel reusing the same context is/not a good idea. Could someone show me how to reference the DbContext in the correct way. I normally have an abstract class which is then added to my classes e.g.

```
    public class CustomerService : DbContxtService, ICustomer
    {
     public void Add(Customer c)
    {
    // Add customer
    }
    }
```

3. How could set the DAL project to retrieve the connection string from my Web forms project (so that i dont need to always change the Class Library and could have one area to change the connection string)

Comment: If these separate projects are not going to be used by any other solution then, IMO, there is no point in making separate projects. Just put everything in one project. "Layers" is a term that makes people think they are doing good architecture but that is just a reference, not a layer.

Comment: Thanks, 1. Yes it would be used by other projects. 2. Are you saying what I have listed in the original thread is the wrong way about doing things?

Comment: 1. please do not use webforms, it is outdated, use MVC.
2. what you are asking about maps to something called Domain Driven Design and Domain Bounded Contexts which is an advanced concept and doing it without proper reasons will actually cause more harm, so I suggest you study those topics thoroughly first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If i want to add another method.. where would I do it.

The entity definitions are [partial classes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/partial-classes-and-methods).  You can add members to the class in a separate file that wouldn't be overwritten.

> How do i reference the DbContext created in DAL project in this project?

You set a reference to the project and add a constructor dependency for each service on your (single) DbContext.

eg

```
public class CustomerService 
{
    private MyDbContext db;
    public CustomerService(MyDbContext db)
    {
       this.db = db;
    {
    public void CreateNewCustomer(Customer c)
    {
       //CRUD and business logic here
       ...
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
    public Customer GetCustomerWithHistory(int customerId)
    {
       db.Customer.Include("SalesOrders").FirstOrDefault( c => c.Id = customerId);
    }

    public void CreateCustomerServiceTicket(Customer c, Incident i)
    {
    }
}
```

Note this should be a business service, not a repository.

Comment: Thanks so I could create a class for all tables (if it makes sense to do so) and follow the pattern above? I googled a business service Vs a repository and to make sure our terminology is the same are you referring this as having an interface or not?

Comment: See examples in update of a business service vs a repository.  The idea is that service handles all the repository actions _and_ domain logic for handling customer service interactions.